# How to mysql database connection with react js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm beginner for React JS. Therefore, I want to learning how can used together React JS, Node JS and MySQL. So, Please give me some advises and example. I try do solve this problem. please help me guys.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to search by yourself first. I literally just pasted your question title into google and got this as first result : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325397/how-to-connect-mysql-database-to-reactjs-app

Comment: You could take a look at NPM packages such as [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials out there to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.js` at the backend folder that is like `server.js` in the backend that you made add these code :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user:'root',
password:'mysqljs123',//password of your mysql db
database:'react-sql-db'
});
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: From the linked question: "**Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes, so if your app has any vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually needs in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup."

Answer (score 3):

You can't add back-end activity using ReactJs.

In Nodejs is possible.

You can connect `MySql` using `sequelize ORM` in nodejs.

> **Sequelize ORM**
>
> Sequelize is a promise-based Node.js ORM for Postgres, MySQL, SQLite and Microsoft SQL Server. It has many solid features for transaction, relations, read replication and more.

Try this:

```
>npm install --save sequelize
>npm install --save mysql2
```

**Setting up Sequelize MySQL connection**

`./app/config/env.js`

```
const env = {
  database: 'testdb',
  username: 'root',
  password: '12345',
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
};
 
module.exports = env;
```

`./app/config/db.config.js`

```
const env = require('./env.js');
 
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(env.database, env.username, env.password, {
  host: env.host,
  dialect: env.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,
 
  pool: {
    max: env.max,
    min: env.pool.min,
    acquire: env.pool.acquire,
    idle: env.pool.idle
  }
});
 
const db = {};
 
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
 
//Models/tables
db.customers = require('../model/customer.model.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
 
 
module.exports = db;
```

**Create Sequelize model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
    firstname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    age: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
  });
  
  return Customer;
}
```

**Route**

`./app/controller/customer.route.js`

```
module.exports = function(app) {
 
    const customers = require('../controller/customer.controller.js');
 
    // Create a new Customer
    app.post('/api/customers', customers.create);
 
    // Retrieve all Customer
    app.get('/api/customers', customers.findAll);
 
    // Retrieve a single Customer by Id
    app.get('/api/customers/:customerId', customers.findById);
 
    // Update a Customer with Id
    app.put('/api/customers/:customerId', customers.update);
 
    // Delete a Customer with Id
    app.delete('/api/customers/:customerId', customers.delete);
}
```

**Controller**

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js');
const Customer = db.customers;
 
// Post a Customer
exports.create = (req, res) => {  
  // Save to MySQL database
  Customer.create({  
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    age: req.body.age
  }).then(customer => {    
    // Send created customer to client
    res.send(customer);
  });
};
 
// FETCH all Customers
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  Customer.findAll().then(customers => {
    // Send all customers to Client
    res.send(customers);
  });
};
 
// Find a Customer by Id
exports.findById = (req, res) => {  
  Customer.findById(req.params.customerId).then(customer => {
    res.send(customer);
  })
};
 
// Update a Customer
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.customerId;
  Customer.update( { firstname: req.body.firstname, lastname: req.body.lastname, age: req.body.age }, 
           { where: {id: req.params.customerId} }
           ).then(() => {
           res.status(200).send("updated successfully a customer with id = " + id);
           });
};
 
// Delete a Customer by Id
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.customerId;
  Customer.destroy({
    where: { id: id }
  }).then(() => {
    res.status(200).send('deleted successfully a customer with id = ' + id);
  });
};
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
 
const db = require('./app/config/db.config.js');
  
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  console.log('Drop and Resync with { force: true }');
});
 
require('./app/route/customer.route.js')(app);
 
// Create a Server
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
 
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
 
  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: Like I quoted in the other answer, do not log in as root.

Comment: isn't this a security issue as you have login details available on the client