# Mysql Express Reactjs Nodejs crud issue using Axios

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

There are three input fields in the form, i want to post data from these input fields to Mysql database table using Axios. i tried many times but i cannot do it, i need code of connection to database + insert query

```
//PostForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
export default class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)   
        this.state = {
            userId:"",
             name:"",
             email:""
        }
    }
    changeHandler =e=>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    submitHandler= e=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const {userId, name, email}= this.state
        console.log(this.state)
        axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.state)
        .then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
    render() {
        const {userId, name, email}= this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                    <input type="text" name="userId" value={userId}  onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input type ="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input type= "text" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>                   
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to provide the BE code, there are plenty of resources, articles and videos that tell you how to create a fullstack CRUD app.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to access is a direct API exposed by MYSQL for insertion, but I'm afraid that is not there.

You will need a backend which handles the connection and executes the insert query on the trigger of an API.

Then you make an API request using Axios and solve the problem at hand.

Comment: var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser= require("body-parser");
var app= express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "reactdb"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO try (ID, Name, Email) VALUES ('userId', 'name', 'email')";  
con.query(sql, function (err, result) 
{  
if (err) throw err;  
console.log("1 record inserted");  
}); 
});

Comment: @AfzalAbbas I understand what you are trying to do, refer to this link for clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325397/how-to-connect-mysql-database-to-reactjs-app