# Node.JS MySQL query not executing with no error

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Despite having correct server credentials this segment of code being called from a function never reaches the alert at the bottom of the snippet nor does it provide any error message despite the inclusion of a throw err statement. It reaches the alert saying "PING" but never even executes the "PONG" alert. What is wrong here? In MySQL Workbench the credentials seem to be correct and I've inserted data into columns using that environment just fine.

```
    alert("PING");
    //Begin SQL query
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : '127.0.0.1',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'password',
      port: 3306,
      database : 'db'
    });
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(err, rows, fields) 
    {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(rows[0]);
    });
    connection.end();
    alert("PONG");
```

Comment: There's no `alert()` function in node? Are you running this in a browser? If so, you'll get an error message for using `require`. Node JavaScript and browser JavaScript are not the same. Requiring modules like that and accessing a DB directly is only possible with node.

Comment: How long did wait for an output before killing the process? it maybe that the mysql server for some reason is not send data back and your nodejs process just wait for it

Comment: @ChrisG Yes there is the first alert executes fine. The second alert never displays and there is no error provided in console.

Comment: The code works fine for me if I remove the `alert` statements and run this from the command line using `node test.js`. If you see an alert displayed, you're running this as <script> in a browser. However `mysql` is a node module, i.e. backend.

Comment: how are you calling alert() and require(mysql)? Could you tell us a little more on how are you running this script?

Comment: Same as @ChrisG, ```node test.js``` works fine.

Comment: @IgnacioAcuña  I am running this is a React environment. Are the alerts what is stopping the query?

Comment: No, the fact that you're trying to use server-side code on the client-side is what's stopping it. React runs inside the browser; you cannot use backend libraries like `mysql` there.

Comment: @ChrisG so how do I test SQL in this environment then?

Comment: I think this could be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325397/how-to-connect-mysql-database-to-reactjs-app

Comment: You need a backend. You can use node + express, or PHP, or some other suitable web framework. You're currently running a node server to develop your React app (I assume) but node is merely used to compile your React modules into a single script and run it in a browser. For db stuff you need an actual backend. Since you have node already set up (I assume), google a [MERN stack tutorial](https://icodemag.com/how-to-build-a-login-register-app-with-the-mern-stack-part-2-setting-up-the-database/) (Mysql, Express, React, Node)

Answer (score 1):

Pass your .query() section as an argument of the .connect() function like this:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if err throw err;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    });
})
```

That should work better.

Comment: Removing the `alert` commands makes OP's code run fine.

Comment: @ChrisG I just removed all of the alerts and it still doesn't work and it doesn't throw any errors. I am working in a React environment and I'm confused as to what is wrong...